# What wire to minimize my wiring loss?

Tags: design, wire-size

(Please be gentle, I am a total novice when it comes to EE...)

I'm working on a design for an "off grid" setup. For... reasons (see comments and edit history, but those details are extraneous to the question) I'm going to be sensitive to any extra-load power use and so will want to minimize that as much as is feasible.

I have multiple 100 mA loads each running off of a single pair of 12 V DC wires. (These are in turn paired off, with either one or two pairs of loads each using a four wire bundle.) Basically, I want to keep my wiring losses under control. Expected operating temperature is 15°C to 30°C *ambient* (but more likely between 20°c and 25°c).

The load and power bank need to be about 1-3 meters apart, and I'd like for the wire to be somewhat flexible. What would be a good choice of wire to use for this setup? (I *think* stranded 18 AWG is enough? Is that overkill? Or should I go lower, e.g. 12 AWG? If I did the math right, the losses from 18 AWG should be <1% the load power?)

Comment: @Hearth, did you read the question? The more things dissipating electricity, the shorter the run time off the capacitors. IIUC this includes the wiring; "worse" wiring → less run time. Again, IIUC this means minimizing resistance in the wiring. That said, I *think* the number of electrons that are going to turn into heat in the wiring are negligible compared to the ones doing useful stuff; I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable than me can confirm...

Comment: So you specifically want to minimize current leakage, or power dissipation?

Comment: @Hearth, I want to minimize the reduction in run time due to the wiring. I'm not sure I understand the distinction in your question (which is quite possible; I'm very much a novice!) or even know exactly what I need to do to accomplish that, just that I feel like the resistance of the wire is going to have some effect. Feel free to edit the question if you know better terminology.

Comment: @Matthew The longer or thinner a wire, the more resistance it has. Resistance causes a _voltage_ drop. The current entering one end equals the current leaving the other end. So, you want to "minimize" the voltage drop. But here is the problem--you can always get a thicker wire. There is no "minimum" resistance (other than 0), just a point where you say, it is not worth the extra cost. How much is reducing the voltage drop by a few millivolts worth to you?

Comment: @Matthew I can't edit the question to clarify, because minimizing power loss, voltage drop, and leakage current are three different (though interrelated) things, and while power and voltage concerns would be addressed in similar ways leakage current is a different beast altogether.

Comment: What is the load? Lights? How is the supercap/battery recharged? Solar cell? What is the ambient temperature range? Civilized, Industrial, or Canadian? Why is it critical to run the power source dry? That sounds weird.

Comment: To minimise current loss, just make sure the cable is well insulated!  More seriously, this is a fairly ridiculous premise for a question : first spec out how much a capacitor capable of storing the required energy will look like, and cost ... then decide which battery to use instead. (Add a BMS to cut it off instead of running dry). THEN worry about these details.

Comment: The question only asks about wire size. Minimum wire size is dictated by the current-carrying capacity (ampacity) of the wire. Search for tables that give that for standard sizes, insulation types, ambient temperature, and number of wires bundled together. Wire size also determine the voltage drop over a distance. Search for a voltage drop calculator. The current and wire resistance determine the power lost in transmission. The question provides irrelevant details and omits essential details. Voting to close.

Comment: @CharlesCowie, maybe you could instead suggest ways to improve the question? Maybe you could allow that *I don't know how this stuff works* and instead of insulting my ignorance, help me to overcome it?

Comment: @Matthew, the problem is that your assumptions are so far off base that we'd have to give you a full semester course in basic electrical power systems before you'd know the right question to ask.

Comment: What Brian is pointing out is that you're basically proposing buying $1000's worth of supercapacitors to avoid buying $100's worth of batteries and a battery management system.

Comment: @ThePhoton, what part of "I *really* want to avoid the additional points of failure of a BMS" is unclear?

Comment: @Matthew, the part where you never said that in your question post. But in any case you're still proposing to trade that for the multiple points of failure due to paralleling many supercapacitors.

Comment: @ThePhoton, "I don't want to mess with ... having to worry about the battery controller", but okay, I made it more explicit. Anyway, I think "thousands" may be a bit of an overstatement; if I did the numbers right (granted, *not* a certainty by any means!), I should be okay with 2-4 of [these](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07D8182C6), or just [this](https://www.ebay.com/i/254684781143). 10 W × 10 h is also an absolute worst-case scenario. It's more important that I can scale capacity and have only as much as I need, which would also be harder with batteries.

Comment: 4 of these https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32998328673.html gives 90Wh for about $16 + shipping; + BMS for less than that. LFP's very flat discharge curve means you can probably eliminate the buck-boost converter you'd need with the caps. So, even if you can get the caps down to a few hundred, a smaller simpler battery system would be my choice. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

> In theory, my 12V load is going to need 3-10W, and I'd like to be able to power it on the order of 1-10 hours.

OK, so 3Wx1h = 3Wh ; 10Wx10h = 100 Wh, quite a range. Let's go with 100 Wh. One Wh is 3600J, so that's 360 kJ.

An average [100F 2.7V supercap](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/AVX/SCCV60B107SRB/?qs=qSfuJ%252Bfl%2Fd7u%2FjAgEAlO4Q%3D%3D) stores 7.2kJ but to get all the joules out you got to discharge it down to 0V at which point it provides no power, so to be realistic you'll only be able to use 75% of the energy, or 5.4 kJ. This means you need 66 caps, for a total cost of €320.

Note that supercaps in series need to be balanced, properly charged and monitored, which makes them just as complicated to use as batteries. On top of that, the varying voltage means you need a DC-DC converter to extract the power, which in the end makes them more complicated than batteries.

Or you could use LiIon cells for much cheaper.

Supercaps aren't what you need. If you want to actuate a mechanism with a solenoid for a long time using low power, then your solution is mechanical. You can use a bistable mechanical latch that is held in place with a spring for example, and only pulse the solenoid when you want to switch from one state to another state. So instead of using power continuously to keep the solenoid energized, you only use power to change from one state to another. You could also use a motor.

If, for example, the solenoid is supposed to hold an object and then drop it when power is cut off, then the solution is to hold the object with a latch or a permanent magnet, and use the solenoid to unlatch the mechanism, or to momentarily cancel the field of the permanent magnet, which drops the object. Note a solenoid with a magnet as a core acts like a "normally on" electromagnet which can be "turned off" by setting the solenoid current to a value that cancels the magnet's field.

As far as wires are concerned, that's irrelevant. There will be tens of meters of wire in the electromagnet, so why worry about another meter of wire to the power source? Just use some wire that's marginally thicker than what's in the solenoid.

Comment: beat me to it by 1 minute E~1/2CV^2 * 10% ^2 for 10% voltage drop. i.e. 1% of initial capacity can be used

Comment: Upvoted for checking my numbers on caps, even though this has nothing to do with the actual question. You lost me at "bistable mechanical latch"; that's a point of failure I'm trying really, *really* hard to avoid. (I'm not even going to comment on some of the other suggestions.)

Comment: I'm curious what the end goal is. Note a magnetic latching solenoid is about as reliable as a permanent magnet, which is... pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your 12V is DC. I am also going to assume that what you wish to minimize is the amount of power dissipated by the wires.

The resistance of 18AWG wire is 21m\$\Omega\$/meter according to [this chart](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/AWG.phtml).

If your wire is 3 meters, the total resistance (out and back) is 2 x 3 x 21 = 126m\$\Omega\$.

The voltage drop due to the resistance of the wires, if you have a 100mA current is 100mA*126m\$\Omega\$ = 12.6mV.

The power lost is 12.6mV x 100 mA = 1.26mW

Comment: You forgot to actually calculate the power dissipated in the wire, if you're talking about power loss. (it'd be about 54.96 mW)

Comment: You forgot to state your assumptions about how the power is distributed among "1-3 sets of 4 wires."

Comment: @CharlesCowie, hopefully the edit to the question clarified that. Each pair of wires, which is up to 3 m long (so 6 m total of wire) drives either a 100 mA or 15 mA load, both in theory at 12 V. (The 15 mA is an LED which I *think* will be resistor-paired to run at 12 V, but might be 3 V or 5 V.) That said, this seems to match the conclusion I came to, which is *worst case* I'm looking at probably 1% or less loss in the wiring even at 18 AWG.

Comment: @Matthew. If your load is only 100mA (or even 15mA) then you are nowhere near 10W. But that only means your voltage drop and power loss will be that much lower.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how much I trust those numbers; 10 W is including some fudge factor. Also that's *per pair*; the total "ideal" load is up to 415 mA, which is ~5 W, plus I still need a voltage regulator, because capacitors. So 10 W is more a conservative estimate of the total draw on the capacitors, not the per-wire draw. But yeah, lower load per wire → lower wire loss → I'm probably worrying too much .

Comment: Oh, and yes, this is all DC. Sorry 'bout that (edited question to clarify).